# How can I generate initialPreview and initialPreviewConfig from the server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input/demo in ASP .Net MVC 5 project, can you help me how I can generate `initialPreview` and `initialPreviewConfig` from server side?

```
public class ImgSetting
{
    public string [] initialPreview { get; set; }
    public ConfigSetting initialPreviewConfig { get; set; }
    public string append { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigSetting
{
    public string caption { get; set; }
    public string width { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string [] extra { get; set; }
}
```

and I tried to make a JSON Array object:

```
ConfigSetting configSetting = new ConfigSetting();
configSetting.caption = file.FileName;
configSetting.width = "120px";
configSetting.url = "/localhost/avatar/delete";
configSetting.key = "100";
configSetting.extra = new string[] {id ="100" };
imgSetting.initialPreview = new string[] {"'<img src='~/Images/"+file.FileName +"' class='file-preview-image' alt='Desert' title='Desert'>'"};
imgSetting.initialPreviewConfig = configSetting;
imgSetting.append = "false";

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imgSetting);

return Json(json);
```

But it's still not working?

Comment: By "it's still not working" what do you mean? Do you have an error you can share with us? See [ask] for more information about asking a good question.

Comment: Also, the `model-view-controller` tag is for the pattern, not the ASP.NET framework. You already had the correct tag for that, so I removed the extra one.